# npm install does not create subfolder in node_modules

Tags: npm

I am having some weird issues. I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to get cordova working. So I first installed some basic stuff (apache2, mysql-server, etc) and then installed npm (sudo apt-get install npm).

Thats all fine, I have a node_modules directory now with a node folder in it. That folder contains package.json.

Now I am trying to install cordova (npm install -g cordova), the download goes well and there are no errors. At the end it references to node_modules/cordova/*

When checking this directory, it does not seem to appear.

npm_modules is in my /var/www/ dir if that matters. I used sudo for all commands.

Comment: if you try to `locate` or `whereis cordova` what do you get?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `npm install -g cordova` will install cordova globally. If you want it to be installed in your current directory only remove the `-g` switch. Also unless you have a very specific purpose there is no need to install node modules in `/var/www`...

Comment: @Salem That may in effect answer the question; you may want to post it, or something like it, as an answer.